# sed substitution on multiple lines

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to substitute `owl:Class` in the following text with the LP number

Input:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="https://loinc.org/LP173100-1">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://loinc.org/LP410935-3"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling (LP)</rdfs:label>
        <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling</skos:prefLabel>
        <loinc:hasCode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">LP173100-1</loinc:hasCode>
    </owl:Class>
```

so that the substituted output looks like the following

Output:

```
<"LP173100-1" rdf:about="https://loinc.org/LP173100-1">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://loinc.org/LP410935-3"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling (LP)</rdfs:label>
        <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling</skos:prefLabel>
        <loinc:hasCode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">LP173100-1</loinc:hasCode>
    </"LP173100-1">
```

I have used `s/\(owl:Class\)\(.*org\/\)\(LP.*\)"/"\3"\2\3/g` for the first line but I don't know how to apply it on the last line. Is there a more elegant solution? I have a huge file where I need to do such substitution.

I am using a CentOS 7.7 machine.

Comment: If you are working with structured data like XML, I would recommend using a dedicated parser like `xmlstarlet` instead of pure text-based tools.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks. For such small edits, won't sed be more handy?

Comment: (1) What was the intent of your edit at 14:08:16Z?  Do you actually want to replace a non-quoted string with a quoted string, or are you using the quotes for emphasis?  There are other (arguably better) ways of emphasizing text.  Please get into the habit of filling in the comment field with the purpose of your edit. (2) The command that you show doesn’t give the result you say you want ***for the first line**.*  Please reconcile this.  (I guess you know how to fix this; if so, do so.  If you don’t know how, say so.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Strictly speaking, you don’t need the ``\(…\)`` around ``owl:Class``. (4) You say you have “a huge file”.  I guess you are showing us the first six lines.  Is the rest of the file random text that doesn’t need to be changed?  Is the file 6000 lines long, consisting of 1000 repetitions of the given six lines?  Or are there more (similar) substitutions that need to be made?  Please describe.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … I would presume that they all begin with ``<owl:Class …`` and that they all have a ``rdf:about`` on the same line that is a URL where `.org/` is immediately followed by a filename that begins with `LP`.  Is there ever anything else on that line (before or after the `>`)?  Are the XML blocks all exactly six lines long?  Do they all end with `⁠    </owl:Class>` on a line by itself?  What variations are there?  Is there other text between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`, and assuming your file only contains the 6 lines as per your example:

```
$ sed -e '1{h; s/\(owl:Class\)\(.*org\/\)\(LP.*\)"/"\3"\2\3"/}; 6{G; s/\(owl:Class\)\(.*org\/\)\(LP.*\)"/"\3"/}'  infile
<"LP173100-1" rdf:about="https://loinc.org/LP173100-1">
      <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://loinc.org/LP410935-3"/>
      <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling (LP)</rdfs:label>
      <skos:prefLabel rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Counseling</skos:prefLabel>
      <loinc:hasCode rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">LP173100-1</loinc:hasCode>
   </"LP173100-1">
$
```

Explanation:

In a regular expression pattern, back-references are used to match the same content as a previously matched subexpression.

Pattern space is the internal sed buffer where sed places, and possibly modifies, the line it reads from the input file.

Hold space is an additional internal sed buffer where sed can hold temporary data.

- `1{...};` Apply commands between the curly braces to the first line only
- `h;` Save the pattern space, i.e. the unmodified first line, to hold space
- `s///` Do the actual search/replace in the pattern space
- `\(owl:Class\)` Search in the pattern space for string "owl:space". The subexpression matched can be recalled by the back-reference \1
- `\(.*org\/\)` As previous, matches " rdf:about="https://loinc.org/", back-reference is \2
- `\(LP.*\)` As previous, matches "LP173100-1", back-reference is \3
- `/"\3"\2\3"/` Output third subexpression string in double quotes, i.e. "LP173100-1", followed by second subexpression string, followed by the third subexpression string, followed by double quote.
- `6{...};` Apply commands between the curly braces to sixth line only
- `G;` Append hold space to pattern space. Note - you lose the leading white space if you use `x`
- `s///` Do the actual search/replace in the pattern space
- `\(owl:Class\)` Search in the pattern space for string "owl:space". The subexpression matched can be recalled by the back-reference \1
- `\(.*org\/\)` As previous, matches "rdf:about="https://loinc.org/ ", back-reference is \2
- `\(LP.*\)` As previous, matches "LP173100-1", back-reference is \3
- `/"\3"/` Output the third subexpression string between double quotes.

Are there other ways of doing this using `sed`?  Absolutely.  Is this the most efficient way of doing it using `sed`?  Probably not.

Comment: (1) Note that the question says “I have a huge file”. (2) You spent seven lines of your answer “showing” that it works, which you could have faked.  I know you didn’t fake it, because I have tested it, and the actual output of your command is what you say it is.  I presume that, if you had faked it, you would have simply pasted the desired output from the question (which your answer ***doesn’t*** produce). (3) But my point is that those seven lines could be better spent *explaining* how your answer works.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'   If you need an explanation as how it works, just ask. As to a huge file, the OP has so far failed to provide more detail, so I went with what was provided.  As regards "answer doesn’t produce", the one character scrivener error has been fixed.  Your insinuation that I may have faked my answer is frankly contemptible.

Comment: @fpmurphy Please explain the code step by step

Comment: @tulamba. Does my solution work for you?

Comment: @fpmurphy Let me try.

Comment: @fpmurphy It did work. Please explain the code step by step so I and others can understand. Thanks so much

Comment: @tulamba. Explanation provided now that you confirmed the solution worked for you.